# Grammar confusion about 'in which'

Tags: grammar

1. ‘The opposition had no room in which to maneuver.’
2. ‘The opposition had no room to maneuver.’

Are the two sentences both correct?
What is the point to adding 'in which' in the first sentence?

Comment: _In which_ isn't 'added to' the first sentence, it is omitted from the second, because in such a short sentence the meaning is clear without it.

Answer (score 1):

Dictionaries (here, [[Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/room)]) have this sense and this particular use of *room*:

> **room** ... [B1;  non-count usage]
>
> the amount of space that someone or something needs:
>
> - *That sofa would take up too much room in the flat.*
> - *James took the books off the little table to make room for the television.*
> - *He's fainted! Don't crowd him – give him room*.
> - *Is there (enough/any) room for me in the car?*
> - [ + to infinitive ] *There's hardly room to move in here.*

And [Dictionary.com](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/lebensraum) has an example of  the full version:

> - *The Germans felt the pressure of other nations around them so they needs must make more Lebensraum – room in which to be free*. [Nine
>   o'clock Talks; Frederic B Kellogg]

As Kate says, it's more realistic to see the shorter version as a deletion rather than the longer one as an expansion. But both are grammatical.

The shorter version is often (far) more idiomatic:

[image]

But the expanded one sometimes, in my opinion, works better:

> - *There is only so much room in which to twirl a 3-yr-old if you don't dismantle the shelves ....*

[[Scottish Mental Health Arts Festival_Though This Be Madness: A Work in Progress](https://www.mhfestival.com/2020/617-though-this-be-madness-a-work-in-progress)]

The more 'room' is prequalified, the more the longer version sounds more reasonable.